# Multiple JPanels in JFrame

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I am writing a simple MySQL GUI driver. I create 2 `JPanels` one for log in and another for listing of databases in MySQL.

I need to show the log in screen first and once the user authenticates will replace the log in `JPanel` with `DatabaseSelector JPanel`.

How can I do it? A friend told me to use `CardLayout` but I am not sure that I can use it. Since the `DatabaseSelector` will be empty.

Comment: Your friends right, follow there advice...

Comment: You still can use it.. Try it, you would have an empty panel

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is right, but ...

You can find all your answers about Layouts in Oracle Java tutorials.

I suggest you that you look there for answers. Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

This is much better than: A friend told me to use ... Because you will learn this, not wait for directions.